# Normal text appears in bold in php list

Tags: php, list, text

When I compile a newsletter in Libre Office and paste it into PHP List the bold text and normal text displays correctly in the draft, but when it is sent to the mailing list or as a test to myself, all the text displays in bold. What am I doing wrong which is causing the normal text to display bold?

Comment: You can have a tag not close? For example a <b> tag.

Comment: Can you paste the HTML that you're working with? More than likely, you missed a closing tag (e.g `</b>` or `</strong>`) when you copied the text.

Answer (score 2):

I think there  is not any problem with your PHP coding, it is occurring because of your HTML coding.

You may use any  or  or any h tags like ( h1,h2 or h3 ) tag before your list.
But did not closed it before starting the list.

So your HTML generated code from PHP is something like this-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Unordered List with Default Bullets</h2>

<b>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>  

</body>
</html>
```

So it is happening.

Please remove extra tags or complete the un completed tags